# Split string each 10 words

Tags: php, regex, split

I want to split a string each 10 words. **But if any word contains a punctuation character,  split after the punctuation character and keep doing split each 10 words.**

I'm using this, but its just split string each 10 words.

```css
<?php

$string = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, te has omnesque gubergren definiebas. Omnesque ullamcorper pri ut. In eos insolens atomorum moderatius, mundi menandri usu cu. Nam an dicant tritani philosophia facete minimum id sed errem omnium persequeris ad his, omnes luptatum recteque mel eu, est te laudem causae.';

$splitted = preg_replace( '~((?:\S*?\s){10})~', "$1\n", $string);

$Words = explode("\n", $splitted);

var_dump($Words);

?>
```

```html
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  string(66) "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, te has omnesque gubergren definiebas. "
  [1]=>
  string(72) "Omnesque ullamcorper pri ut. In eos insolens atomorum moderatius, mundi "
  [2]=>
  string(66) "menandri usu cu. Nam an dicant tritani philosophia facete minimum "
  [3]=>
  string(64) "id sed errem omnium persequeris ad his, omnes luptatum recteque "
  [4]=>
  string(29) "mel eu, est te laudem causae."
}
```

I want to get these results, Split the string every 10 words **But if any word contains a punctuation character, split after the punctuation character and** keep doing split every 10 words

```html
array(6) {
  [0]=>
  string() "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, te has omnesque gubergren definiebas. "
  [1]=>
  string() "Omnesque ullamcorper pri ut."
  [2]=>
  string() "In eos insolens atomorum moderatius, mundi  menandri usu cu."
  [3]=>
  string() "Nam an dicant tritani philosophia facete minimum id sed errem"
  [4]=>
  string() "omnium persequeris ad his, omnes luptatum recteque mel eu, est"
  [5]=>
  string() "te laudem causae."
}
```

Comment: Google: `PHP wordwrap()`

Comment: I can split words already, but if before 10 words has contains punctuation character; its should split after there, and keep doing these.

Comment: @MertKaya, To me it is not 100% certain what you want.  Maybe you should give an example.

Comment: Something like `'/(\b\S+(?:\s+\S+){9})\s*/'` and replace with `'$1\n'`? Like [this](https://regex101.com/r/rB3vT3/1)? If not, please provide your own test fiddle.

Comment: I added a test fiddle, Can you check it ?

Comment: The link is not working. Also, please do not only put code on external sites - also put it in your question.

Comment: I'm curious as to why you'd have an arbitrary ten word cut-off? Is this natural language text or some kind of weirdly formatted data string? Also, what kind of punctuation are you looking to break at? Remember that some punctuation can occur mid-word.

Comment: Anders, Can you check it now ?

Comment: Simba they can be {. or , or : or ;} Do you have any idea?

Comment: What is your expected result?

Comment: Try to split each 10 words, but if words contains some (. , : ;) characters, split directly from there and keep continue split each 10 words

Comment: Sorry, I don't get you. Please, edit your question and give the expected result.

Comment: Toto, I put here what i expected result. Can you check it

Comment: See my answer. I've given 2 possibilities, split on comma or not.

Answer (score 3):

Is that what you want?

```
$string = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, te has omnesque gubergren definiebas. Omnesque ullamcorper pri ut. In eos insolens atomorum moderatius, mundi menandri usu cu. Nam an dicant tritani philosophia facete minimum id sed errem omnium persequeris ad his, omnes luptatum recteque mel eu, est te laudem causae.';
$splitted = preg_replace( '~((?:[^\s\pP]+[\s\pP]){1,10})~', "$1\n", $string);
$Words = explode("\n", $splitted);
var_dump($Words);
```

`\pP` stands for any punctuation character.

**Output:**

```
array(10) {
  [0]=>
  string(27) "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,"
  [1]=>
  string(38) " te has omnesque gubergren definiebas."
  [2]=>
  string(29) " Omnesque ullamcorper pri ut."
  [3]=>
  string(37) " In eos insolens atomorum moderatius,"
  [4]=>
  string(23) " mundi menandri usu cu."
  [5]=>
  string(63) " Nam an dicant tritani philosophia facete minimum id sed errem "
  [6]=>
  string(26) "omnium persequeris ad his,"
  [7]=>
  string(32) " omnes luptatum recteque mel eu,"
  [8]=>
  string(22) " est te laudem causae."
  [9]=>
  string(0) ""
}
```

If you don't want to split on comma, use this :

```
$splitted = preg_replace( '~((?:[^\s.:;]+[\s.:;]){1,10})~', "$1\n", $string);
```

Answer (score 2):

I would go with this:

```
$text_array = explode(" ", $string); 
$chunks = array_chunk($text_array, 10);
echo print_r($chunks, true);
```

output should be like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Lorem
            [1] => ipsum
            [2] => dolor
            [3] => sit
            [4] => amet,
            [5] => te
            [6] => has
            [7] => omnesque
            [8] => gubergren
            [9] => definiebas.
        )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => Omnesque
        [1] => ullamcorper
        [2] => pri
        [3] => ut.
        [4] => In
        [5] => eos
        [6] => insolens
        [7] => atomorum
        [8] => moderatius,
        [9] => mundi
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => menandri
        [1] => usu
        [2] => cu.
        [3] => Nam
        [4] => an
        [5] => dicant
        [6] => tritani
        [7] => philosophia
        [8] => facete
        [9] => minimum
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [0] => id
        [1] => sed
        [2] => errem
        [3] => omnium
        [4] => persequeris
        [5] => ad
        [6] => his,
        [7] => omnes
        [8] => luptatum
        [9] => recteque
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [0] => mel
        [1] => eu,
        [2] => est
        [3] => te
        [4] => laudem
        [5] => causae.
    )
```

)

Comment: I added a test fiddle, Can you check it ?